# Get fallback locale when device locale strings.xml is not present

Tags: android, kotlin, localization

Per the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/multilingual-support#postN), Android 7 and above will use baked-in fallback logic to identify which resources to present to the user in a locale that most closely matches the user's. The example given in the docs has the unsupported fr_CH falling back to the supported fr_FR, which is the same language, different country code. So if the user's device is in fr_CH, they'll see fr_FR assets/strings/etc.

Is it possible to get that fallback locale value? That is to say (using the example above), given that I have a user whose device is in fr_CH and my app supports fr_FR, **does Android provide a way to inform me that fr_FR is the fallback locale that will be used?**

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer exactly, but a workaround I found to be effective given my use case. Requires a bit of tedious manual setup.

In my use case, I assume that all string keys will exist in all the strings.xml files in the app. That is to say that if I have a key "my_string_key", I assume it's in every locale's strings.xml that I have bundled with the app.

With that assumption, I created a key "zzz_resolution_locale_bcp_code" in each strings.xml file. This key holds the locale of that strings.xml file as its value. For instance, in my strings.xml file in my resource directory **values-b+es+419**, the entry is

```
<string name="zzz_resolution_locale_bcp_code">es-419</string>
```

When I instantiate my localization manager, I set up the resources object based on the user's language prefs (user has an in-app option to choose a language that's different than their device language):

```
val locale = Locale(language, marketplace)
// Create a new Configuration based on the old one, we just put in the new Locale
val overrideConf = Configuration(context.resources.configuration)
overrideConf.setLocale(localeOverride)
val localizedContext = context.createConfigurationContext(overrideConf)

return localizedContext.resources
```

and call getString("zzz_resolution_locale_bcp_code") using that resource object. If the app supports the language, then the return value will reflect the same language and marketplace that I used to set up the locale.  If the return value is *different*, I know that locale's strings.xml file Android is going to be used when getting the rest of the strings for the app.

For example, say the user's device is in es-CR (Costa Rican Spanish) and they have not selected an in-app language override. We set up the resources object for es-CR, then call getString on "zzz_resolution_locale_bcp_code". It returns "es-419" because the app doesn't support es-CR, and Android's fallback system eventually found its way to the strings.xml file in my **values-b+es+419** directory.

Tedious bit is ensuring that each strings.xml file has the "zzz_resolution_locale_bcp_code" key and that the value doesn't get autotranslated via your translation service. Best thing I've come up with so far though; I'll update this post if I find something that works better.

Appreciate feedback and suggestions (or completely different approaches) of anyone who finds their way to this post!